# Laravel Phpunit testing a request that take give output based on the request

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm still new to laravel and I have a simple app and aSo I have a route that will store data based on the request in my controller.

```
  public funtion store(Request $request, $id){
          if ($request->has('work_experiences')) {
            WorkExperience::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'position' => $request->work_experiences['position'],
                'company' => $request->work_experiences['company'],
                'start_date' => $request->work_experiences['start_date'],
                'end_date' => $request->work_experiences['end_date'],
            ]);
        }
        if ($request->has('education')) {
            Education::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'degree' => $request->education['degree'],
                'university' => $request->education['university'],
                'start_date' => $request->education['start_date'],
                'end_date' => $request->education['end_date'],
            ]);
        }
        if ($request->has('job_interests')) {
            JobInterest::create([
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'job_position' => $request->job_interests['position'],
            ]);
        }}
}
```

and in my test

```
public function test_authenticated_user_can_edit_education_profile()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $user = User::factory()->create();
    $this->actingAs($user);
    $response = $this->post('/candidate' . '/' . $user->id, [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'position' => 'position',
        'company' => 'company',
        'start_date' => Carbon::now(),
        'end_date' => Carbon::now(),
    ]);

    $this->assertCount(1, WorkExperience::all());
}
```

when I run the test, the assertCount seems to fail because the response didn't work/insert the data to DB. where do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the test is right.

It should fail because there is no `work_experiences` key in your request data.

The test request should look like:

```php
$response = $this->post('/candidate' . '/' . $user->id, [
    'work_experiences' => [
        'user_id' => $user->id,
        'position' => 'position',
        'company' => 'company',
        'start_date' => Carbon::now(),
        'end_date' => Carbon::now(),
    ]
]);
```

So your data should go under a `work_experiences` key such that `$request->has('work_experiences')` returns true and executes the `WorkExperience::create()` statement.

---

Currently your endpoint only allows for a single "work experience" to be created. Seeing that you've named it `work_experiences` I assume you'd want to pass in an array/collection of "work experiences" - but that won't work with the current implementation; you'll have to loop over them instead - something like this:

```
if ($request->has('work_experiences')) {
    foreach ($request->input('work_experiences') as $experience) {
        WorkExperience::create([
            'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
            'position' => $experience['position'],
            'company' => $experience['company'],
            'start_date' => $experience['start_date'],
            'end_date' => $experience['end_date'],
        ]);
    }
}
```

And then your test should look something like this:

```php
$response = $this->post('/candidate' . '/' . $user->id, [
    'work_experiences' => [
        [
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'position' => 'position',
            'company' => 'company',
            'start_date' => Carbon::now(),
            'end_date' => Carbon::now(),
        ],
        // more "work experiences"
    ]
]);
```